# Form application method error

Tags: c#, calculator

It is telling me that the method I made named Calculate "not all code paths return a value"
This is homework in case you were wondering, I am a first year programming student. I just want to get rid of this error, if i change it to static method it goes away but then i run into problem with the validation errors i made.

```
    private decimal Calculate(decimal operand1, decimal operand2, string operator1)
    {
        //Declarations
        decimal operandOne;
        decimal operandTwo;
        string operatorOne = "";
        const string divide = "/";
        const string multiply = "*";
        const string addition = "+";
        decimal calcResult = 0m;

        try
        {
            if (IsValidData())
            {

                // try to get the user input from the form
                operandOne = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperandOne.Text);
                operandTwo = Convert.ToDecimal(txtOperandTwo.Text);
                operatorOne = Convert.ToString(txtOperator.Text);

                if (operatorOne == divide)
                {
                    calcResult = operandOne / operandTwo;

                }
                else if (operatorOne == multiply)
                {
                    calcResult = operandOne * operandTwo;

                }
                else if (operatorOne == addition)
                {
                    calcResult = operandOne + operandTwo;

                }
                else
                {
                    calcResult = operandOne - operandTwo;

                }
                return (Math.Round(calcResult, 4));

            }

        }
        catch (FormatException myFormatEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myFormatEx.Message + "\nInvalid numeric format. Please check all entries.", "Entry Error");
        }
        catch (OverflowException myOverflowEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myOverflowEx.Message + "\nOverflow error. Please enter smaller values.", "Entry Error");
        }
        catch (Exception myEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(myEx.Message + "\n\n" + myEx.GetType().ToString() + "\n" + myEx.StackTrace, "Exception");
        }


    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //DECLARATIONS
        decimal calcResult;
        decimal operandOne = 0m;
        decimal operandTwo = 0m;
        string operatorOne = "";

        //PROCESSING
        calcResult = Calculate(operandOne, operandTwo, operatorOne);

        //OUTPUT
        lblResult.Text = calcResult.ToString("d"); // in decimal format


    }
    private bool IsValidData()
    {
        // This method checks all the textboxes on the form for valid entries


        return
            // Validate the OperandOne text box
            IsPresent(txtOperandOne, "First Operator") &&
            IsDecimal(txtOperandOne, "First Operator") &&


            // Validate the OperandTwo text box
            IsPresent(txtOperandTwo, "Second Operator") &&
            IsDecimal(txtOperandTwo, "Second Operator") &&


            // Validate the Operator text box
            IsPresent(txtOperator, "Operator /,*,+ or -") &&
            IsOperator(txtOperator, "Operator /,*,+ or -");
    }
    public bool IsOperator(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        // this method makes sure a textbox is a valid operator
        string validOperators = "";
        bool valid = true;
        try
        {
            validOperators = Convert.ToString(textBox.Text); // try to convert




            if (validOperators != "/" | validOperators != "*" | validOperators != "+" | validOperators != "-") // not valid entry
            {
                MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a valid operator +,-,/,* Entry Error");
                textBox.SelectAll();
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException myFormatEx)
        {
            textBox.SelectAll(); // Select the user's entry
            throw myFormatEx; // throw to the calling method to handle
        }
        catch (OverflowException myOverflowEx)
        {
            throw myOverflowEx; // throw to the calling method to handle
        }
        catch (Exception myEx)
        {
            throw myEx; // throw to the calling method to handle
        }
        return valid;

    }
    public bool IsPresent(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        // this method checks any textbox for a required entry
        bool valid = true; // assuming valid 
        if (textBox.Text == "") // check to see if there is an entry
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " is a required field.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.Focus(); // set the focus
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }

    public bool IsDecimal(TextBox textBox, string name)
    {
        // this method checks any textbox for a valid decimal entry
        bool valid = true; // assuming valid 

        try
        {
            Convert.ToDecimal(textBox.Text);
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(name + " must be a decimal value.", "Entry Error");
            textBox.SelectAll(); // Select the user's entry
            valid = false;
        }
        catch (OverflowException myOverflowEx)
        {
            throw myOverflowEx; // throw to the calling method to handle
        }
        catch (Exception myEx)
        {
            throw myEx; // throw to the calling method to handle
        }

        return valid;
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //End program
        this.Close();
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

`Calculate` doesn't return anything if `IsValidData()` returns false. It *must* return something for *all* code paths.

Answer (score 1):

If (!IsValidData()) and if there's an exception, what's will be returned.

Answer (score 1):

After your exception handling you need to return a value - obviously you don't have a valid value at this point so you should

```
return 0M;
```

at the end of the method.

Comment: thank you, I was having trouble figureing out how to place that in.